# Python unexpected (to me) behaviour when deleting lists

Tags: python, list, append

Bumped into a programming issue that puzzles me a bit.
Im parsing data and:

- add each relevant chunk to *list1*, append list1 to *final_list*. (for easy and neat future presentation)
- For next relevant piece of information I'm deleting the "old" information in list1 with *list1[:] = []
- append the new fresh information to *list1*, append *list1* to final_list and voilà... I thought :)

All help appreciated!

**Example:**

```
final_list=[]
list1 = [1,2,3,4]
list2 = [5,6,7,8]

final_list.append(list1)
final_list.append(list2)
print final_list

list1[:] = []
print final_list
```

**Example output**

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]]
[[], [5, 6, 7, 8]]
```

**Sys.version**

```
Python: 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:24:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: W hat did you expect to happen?

Comment: I'm not sure why this surprises you. Can you explain what you expect to see?

Comment: Hi, what i want to accheive essentially is to create a list of lists. Keep adding data to final_list from within a loop.

Comment: @Fredrik, is you say something is not as you expected, you should say what you expected or what you find confusing. In this case, I think what you find confusing is that list1 has also changed in the final_list, right? In any case, this is a very common problem when you start working with python. The final_list contains two "labels" that point towards list1 and list2, to WHATEVER you put there. If you change list1 or list2, final_list is changed accordingly

Comment: Why did you empty one of the lists then?

Comment: Tanks for the clarification Jblasco.  Its clear that its a flaw with my original idea of how to add multiple rows of values to final_list for easy presentation.

Comment: For completeness are there any suggestions on how to add multiple rows of values to a list from within a loop.  So that its easily presented later by: "for row in final_list  --> print row"

Comment: *sigh* Yes, there were suggestions in both answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By calling `list1[:] = []`, you change the previous value of all `list1` everywhere, even in `final_list`. To preserve the `list1` value in `final_list`, you should make a copy and append the copy instead of the original list. Some explanations and nice methods for list copying can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list-in-python).

Answer (score 1):

> I'm deleting the "old" information in list1 with *list1[:] = []

So, `list1` is going to be the same object you're referencing in `final_list`.

`final_list` is simply `[list1, list2]`. Hence the output.

If you want a fresh object, reassign the variable:

```
list1 = []
```

Answer (score 1):

As many community readers pointed out, the objects within final_list are only pointers to the original objects "list1" and "list2". In the end i used the method **final_list.append(list(list1))** to store the value of list1 within final_list. (As a copy) After this its safe to reset list1 and repeat the process.